How will the number of samples per update impact the EM algorithm?
I am using an iterative maximum likelihood method to fit a probabilistic distribution. Specifically, I am using von-Mises-Fisher mixture model (spherical Gaussian mixture), and there is indeed closed-form iterative E-M update formula. However, it's extremely time consuming for me to draw samples on a tight performance budget, so I may only use no more than 4 samples (1 or 2 samples is desirable) per update.
I've already know that, for VMM (I am using a two-component VMM in 3D space, meaning that there are two vMF distributions, each sample is a 3D unit vector), using only one sample will break the estimation mathematically (see this material, Equation 13 and 14) since the spherical variance will be infinite. Yet, using only two samples, together with parameter average (with the old parameters, for example, convex mixing) will still produce bad estimates, specifically, the spherical variance is small ($\kappa$ is huge, and the PDF is concentrated around the samples). This is of course undesirable.
My question is:

Is there any golden standard describing the relationship between the number of samples needed and the estimation performance?
How are EM or other MLE method influenced by the scarcity of samples, per iteration?
Is there any suggestion on making this so-called sparse sample MLE problem more robust and accurate?


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
